# Water-stable organoaluminum compounds in which aluminum is part of the aromatic ring

Tags: organic-chemistry

The more common organoaluminum compounds, such as trialkylaluminum, decompose on contact with oxygen-containing molecules (water, ethanol etc). However, my guess is that organoaluminum compounds with an aluminum atom being part of the aromatic system might be more stable towards oxygen compounds, since the high affinity for oxygen of aluminum could be (at least partially) offset by the high energy barrier to destroying the aromatic ring.

My questions are- is my guess correct, and is there any specific aromatic organoaluminum compound that is not destroyed (or acts reversibly at the worst) with water, ethanol, THF (etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not going to get what you want putting aluminum into an aromatic ring.  Aluminum and carbon have relatively poor pi overlap, so your ring will not have the full delocalization necessary for string aromatic stabilization.  And even strong aromatic stabilization may not be all that strong compared with aluminum preferring to bond with oxygen or nitrogen rather than carbon.

Instead of trying to design a compound that somehow tames the reactivity of aluminum-carbon bonds, choose the right polar solvent.  Protic solvents are bad.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organoaluminium_chemistry), organoaluminum compounds "readily form adducts with bases such as pyridine, THF and tertiary amines. These adducts are tetrahedral at Al."  The named examples are **aprotic and coordinate through nitrogen or oxygen**.